# Material UI BottomNavigation is not sticky by default

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

How to make [`BottomNavigation`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-bottom-navigation/) component sticky? Why it's not sticky by default?

Comment: You can take a look at [Snackbar](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e2c500f244f5c1cd1bd35f007c8c746fd52ac27f/src/Snackbar/Snackbar.js#L30) implementation.

Comment: `Snackbar` is a start but the implementation of [`AppBar`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e2c500f244f5c1cd1bd35f007c8c746fd52ac27f/src/AppBar/AppBar.js) probably produces the results closest to the desired behavior.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can make `BottomNavigation` stick to the bottom of your screen with the following CSS:

```
const styles = {
  stickToBottom: {
    width: '100%',
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: 0,
  },
};
```

And then applying it to your `BottomNavigation` component:

```
<BottomNavigation className={classes.stickToBottom}>
```

You should be aware that the `position: 'fixed'` will cause the the bottom navigation component to cover up your content (similarly, the `AppBar` stickied to the top of your screen also covers up content if you do not use a margin). You'll need to provide a `marginBottom` or some other kind of padding to ensure none of your content is hidden.

You can also play around with some of the other `position` options, such as `sticky` or `absolute`. However, in my experience, `fixed` is the option that most closely suits your needs.

Comment: Worth noting: the Appbar is responsively sized, so this padding needs to be adjusted for different viewport sizes.  This can be done using the Toolbar mixin.

Comment: @KenGregory The `Toolbar` mixin is a good solution for adjusting padding to the `AppBar` size. Unfortunately, since the padding in this question needs to match the `BottomNavigation` size, it isn't applicable in this case.

Comment: You mentioned the Appbar, I'm mentioning the toolbar mixin in reference to that aside.

Comment: @KenGregory Right...it's just that this is a question about the `BottomNavigation` component, so I want to be clear that the `Toolbar` mixin is not an appropriate solution for padding the `BottomNavigation` component.

Comment: @JulesDupont Yup, finally we will end up using css to make it sticky to the bottom. And how about my second question, just wondering, should it sticky to the bottom by default? since its name already BottomNavigation XD or is there any cases or there is a guideline where this component doesn't always have to be use sticky at the bottom?

Comment: @KrisMP I didn't participate in the design or implementation of the `BottomNavigation` component in material-ui, so I can't give you a definitive answer as to why it was done this way. However, I can tell you that there are cases in the [official Google guidlines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs) (like scroll) where the bottom nav disappears. If you want a more definitive answer you might want to file an issue on the [material-ui github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui). This might just be a design oversight.

Comment: `classes` is undefined for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

To whom needs to use it inside an `AppBar`, mixing won't cause any padding conflict.

```
  <AppBar position="fixed" color="primary" style={{top: "auto", bottom: 0}}>
    <BottomNavigation value={0} onChange={(event, newValue) => {}}>
      <BottomNavigationAction label="One" icon={<LocationOnIcon/>}/>
      <BottomNavigationAction label="Two" icon={<LocationOnIcon/>}/>
    </BottomNavigation>
  </AppBar>
```

Comment: This will not produce semantic HTML. The AppBar will render a `<header>` tag around the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of the `BottomNavigation` to `fixed` and `bottom` to `0` to put it at the bottom of the viewport.

```
<BottomNavigation sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, width: 1.0 }}
```

But a `fixed` element is taken out of the normal document flow, and may overlap with the content of the body. One way to solve it is to set the `paddingBottom` of the content based on the height of the `BottomNavigation` (which currently from the source [is `56px`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/BottomNavigation/BottomNavigation.js#L27))

```
<Box paddingBottom='56px'>
  <Content />
</Box>
<BottomNavigation sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, width: 1.0 }}>
  <BottomNavigationAction label="Recents" icon={<RestoreIcon />} />
  <BottomNavigationAction label="Favorites" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />
  <BottomNavigationAction label="Archive" icon={<ArchiveIcon />} />
</BottomNavigation>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Reference

- https://mui.com/components/bottom-navigation/#fixed-positioning

Answer (score -1):

You could change the `<header>` by `component` attribute of the `AppBar`.